# is this possible to divide the percentage of split for token?

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment, hardhat

Hi I am very new in Ethereum and smart contract development and trying to make a smart contract where a token can be divided or we can say can be spliced into two parts for e.g,

we have 1ETH, we sliced it and make two parts of 0.5 ETH.
and send both parts to different smart contracts or functions.

I am looking for some code snippets as well but didn't found any on the web yet if anyone knows how to code this please help me with the code also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to split a token up.

It's all dependent on the number of decimal places that token has.(This is a property of the token and not an amount value)

For Example: Ethereum has a property: Decimal Places = 18; thus you can get as little as 0.000000000000000001 ETH

**However**, if the token has 0 decimal places, then it can't be split.

Comment: Are you trying to say we can't slice 1Eth but 1.1ETH can be sliced?

Comment: No, Ethereum has 18 Decimal places. So you can go as little as 0.000000000000000001 ETH.

This is a property of the Coin itself.

So think about property and not amount.

Comment: ok now I got your point but can you show me a simple code so I can try to build this to reality?

Comment: You'll have to ask that in a separate question. Please accept this one and ask another

Comment: your answer is correct, so I edited my question now you can share the code.

Comment: So what precisely does your code need to do?

Comment: just need to split the token into two equal parts

Comment: When what happens?

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: I am asking, what must happen for the token to be split?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128514/discussion-between-mohit-chandel-and-avocadochocolate).